# Session not created: this version of chromedriver only supports chrome version 81 (sessionnotcreated) on hackerrank during run test

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, .net-core

I downgraded my chrome on my local machine and tests was successful. But i don't know how to fix it on hacker rank. I submitted my code on hacker rank and getting below error while running test cases for submitting the code.

We don't have permission to do anything in test project. we can only make changes in main project.

**Error:**

**system.invalidoperationexception : session not created: this version of chromedriver only supports chrome version 81 (sessionnotcreated) on hackerrank during run test**